# OpenGL in C# in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl

I have to write a simple program that will draw something in a Windows Forms Application using OpenGL and C#? Can you give me example of library and/or maybe a tutorial?
I found this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/csgl/files/CsGL/1.4.1/ but it is from 2002. Is there anything newer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could check this out: http://opentk.net/

> The Open Toolkit is set of fast, low-level C# bindings for OpenGL, OpenGL ES and OpenAL. It runs on all major platforms and powers hundreds of apps, games and scientific research.
>
> OpenTK provides several utility libraries, including a math/linear algebra package, a windowing system, and input handling.

Comment: +1 Used OpenTK a few times - it's a pretty decent OpenGL wrapper. Nice thing is it doesn't just expose a bunch of P/Invokes

Comment: Sadly GLControl doesn't work as a NuGet package, so it's quite hard to get WinForms+OpenTK running together in one window.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is [SharpGL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/sharpgl.aspx) on Code Project.

Comment: This library is useless. Sample program with SharpGL control (that does nothing, just displaying black rectangle) needs over 500 MB memory!!!

Comment: @Miko - sorry about that. I'm just presenting it as an alternative. I came across both, but haven't had chance to try either. Thanks for heads up. I'll leave this answer here so future searchers can see your comment.