# Increasing performance of real-time 2D plots w. C#

Tags: c#, plot

I would like to draw 2D plots to display incoming data (multichannel at >20ksps). Using Visual Studio C# and .NET

Graphics.DrawLines () in .NET is easy to use but SLOW.

On my system I have Open GL available.

1. Using a win32 function (LineTo? Polyline?) alternative to C# could be faster. I would appreciate a code snippet to help me out. Should I have the native code in a DLL and use DllImport? Then pass a vector with multiple (x,y) pairs to the DLL function and calling the win32 from the DLL to get the plot drawn?
2. Could Open GL be worth trying? The CPU would still need to pass the (x,y) pairs to OpenGL but connecting the dots with lines would probably be accelerated by hardware. Any pointers to code snippets to get started would be much appreciate?

Your views on the general topic of accelerating 2D plots to show real-time audio-like signals would also be appreciated. (using Visual Studio 2008 for Windows CE 7 embedded .NET 3.5).

Comment: What UI technology are you using? Windows Forms?

Comment: Yes, Windows Forms.

Comment: Is your question maybe a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634674/opengl-in-c-sharp-in-winforms) one?

Comment: The post you quote is useful. Thanks. But my question overlaps only partially. I don't need or want to use OpenGL, I am (more generally) interested in increasing speed of my 2D plots. Currently using DrawLines. Which native code could I use? Or, alternatively, would OpenGL help to speed up plotting? what would be the minimal sample code to try either one of those solutions?

Comment: I guess as only you know your current code and requirements, you'd be the one to create a minimal example in another technology for your problem. Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629056/plot-a-graph-x-y-in-c-sharp-using-opentk) for example?

Comment: Thanks again for this link. It is useful again. I was hoping for simple calls  to win32 functions, avoiding wrapper code like OpenTk. Since I am using an embedded board running Windocs Compact Embedded, the leaner the better.